# How do I save the output variable from terragrunt apply as regular shell environment variable?

Tags: bash, terraform

After running my `terragrunt apply-all` in my CI step (so basically a bash script) I get my outputs, in this case I only have one:

```
output "cloudrun-hostname" {
  value       = google_cloud_run_service.cloudrun.status[0].url
  description = "API endpoint URL"
}
```

How do I pass the value of that output to the environment variable so basically like I exported a variable like this:

```
export HOSTNAME=terragrunt-cloudrun-hostname-output
```

I need this variable with that value so I can envsub the value in another file later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `terraform output`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) command, i.e.

```
export MY_ENV=$(terraform output cloudrun-hostname)
```

after your `apply-all`.

Comment: I found out that only terragrunt output-all work for me for some reason. Then I just grep the value from all the lines.

Comment: I bet `output-all` in Terragrunt uses `output` in Terraform. So I am not surprised.

Also - I think it's cleaner not to **parse** Terragrunt or Terraform output.

Comment: Yes of course. Terragrunt literally shows you the Terraform commands it used such as `terraform output cloudrun-hostname` but when I try to copy Terragrunt and use the same commands it used then I get errors. Ironically Terragrunt documentation claims that `output-all` command is sort of broken.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to expand the command and so:

```
export HOSTNAME="$(terragrunt apply-all | awk -F= '/value/ { gsub(" ","",$2);print $2 }')"
```

Comment: Of course but what is `terragrunt-cloudrun-hostname-output`? That was just a substitute for the real command or value.

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer parse the output with awk.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. `terragrunt-cloudrun-hostname-output` doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: OK, so it should be terragrunt apply-all?